# Synonym for "pivotal" but with a negative outcome connotation

Tags: meaning, synonyms, connotation

Am I mistaken that the word "pivotal" has a positive connotation?  The outcome that is the subject of the pivotol thing is typically a positive outcome?  If so, is there a synonym for pivotol, but where the outcome is negative?

Comment: What part of your research shows *pivotal* having a positive connotation? I find it to be neutral at [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivotal) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pivotal).

Comment: [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144829?redirectedFrom=pivotal#eid)  seems 'constructive' or 'positive' to me. _1. Of, relating to, or acting as a pivot; being that on which anything turns or depends; central, crucial, vital._ I agree that the usage, especially in journalism is a positive turn to something better. 'Pivotal' research is always a step in the right direction of better understanding.

Comment: My research is pretty lite.  Google comes up with this definition: "of crucial importance in relation to the development or success of something else" (of course "success" here can be mean the success of something bad, but that doesn't quite feel right).  Mostly it's just my personal experience of hearing this word used in conversation or reading news containing the word.

Comment: 'Pivotal' research which indicated that a vaccine for Covid-19 would be impossible, would be widely viewed as a bad outcome, and negative news. But that would not affect the correct use of the word 'pivotal' and would not require the use of an antonym.